# Docker and Yaml issue Rocket chat

Tags: docker, ubuntu, yaml, rocket.chat

Setting up a Team Chat Rocket chat using the AWS guidelines https://docs.rocket.chat/installation/paas-deployments/aws/

I'm at the final stages of configuration using docker after adjusting the yaml code below to match my domain.

```
version: '2'

 services:
   rocketchat:
     image: rocket.chat:latest
     command: >
       bash -c
         "for i in `seq 1 30`; do
           node main.js &&
           s=$$? && break || s=$$?;
           echo \"Tried $$i times. Waiting 5 secs...\";
           sleep 5;
         done; (exit $$s)"
     restart: unless-stopped
     volumes:
       - ./uploads:/app/uploads
     environment:
       - PORT=3000
       - ROOT_URL=https://my.domain.xxx
       - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/rocketchat
       - MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/local
     depends_on:
       - mongo
     ports:
       - 3000:3000

   mongo:
     image: mongo:4.0
     restart: unless-stopped
     command: mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --replSet rs0 --storageEngine=mmapv1
     volumes:
       - ./data/runtime/db:/data/db
       - ./data/dump:/dump

   # this container's job is just to run the command to initialize the replica set.
   # it will run the command and remove himself (it will not stay running)
   mongo-init-replica:
     image: mongo:4.0
     command: >
       bash -c
         "for i in `seq 1 30`; do
           mongo mongo/rocketchat --eval \"
             rs.initiate({
               _id: 'rs0',
               members: [ { _id: 0, host: 'localhost:27017' } ]})\" &&
           s=$$? && break || s=$$?;
           echo \"Tried $$i times. Waiting 5 secs...\";
           sleep 5;
         done; (exit $$s)"
     depends_on:
     - mongo
```

I get the following error and have exhausted all options:

```
sudo docker-compose up -d


ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: expected '<document start>', but found '<scalar>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 29, column 1
```

Any help will be appreciated with an explanation why this is occurring.

TIA.

Comment: As you've written this in the question, `services:` is indented.  Is it in your actual file?  That would lead to a YAML parse error.  If that's not it, which line is line 29?

Comment: Line 29 on the AWS page shows as,  restart: unless-stopped

Comment: Beofre you try and run the Yaml file you enter the directory:

`cd /opt/docker/rocket.chat`

When listing the file in this directory you find `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: The majority of the set up is copy and paste from AWS site just changing domain name variables . I cannot understand why incorrect code would be published which hasn't been tried and tested.

Answer (score 0):

Was an issue with the docker reinstalled using a different method and works fine